# Conservation of angular momentum in centre of mass reference frame

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, conservation-laws

If a rigid body is in arbitrary, non-rectilinear motion, a reference system connected with its centre of mass is non-inertial. If there is no external torque acting on this body is its angular moementum conserved in that system? If it is, how can we prove it?

Comment: If you have no external torque, but a force _not_ through the center of mass then angular momentum _is not_ conserved. The problem is ill-posed.

Answer (score 1):

> If there is no external torque acting on this body is its angular moementum conserved in that system? If it is, how can we prove it?

It is easily proved that it isn't, at least in general. The time derivative of some vector quantity $\vec u$ from the perspective of a body-fixed frame versus the the derivative of the same vector quantity from the perspective of an inertial frame are related via
$$\frac{d}{dt}_{\text{inertial}} \vec u = \frac{d}{dt}_{\text{body-fixed}} \vec u + \vec\omega \times \vec u$$
Setting $\vec u$ to $\vec L = \mathrm I\,\vec \omega$ (angular momentum) and setting $\frac{d}{dt}_{\text{inertial}}\, \vec L \equiv 0$ (no external torques) yields $\frac {d\vec L}{dt}_{\text{body_fixed}} = - \omega \times (\mathrm I \, \vec \omega)$. This is non-zero if if the angular velocity is non-zero and is not directed along or against a principal axis.

In other words, angular momentum as expressed in a body-fixed frame is not conserved when the body is rotating and the rotation is not about a principal axis.

Comment: You are right. But I was thinking about a system of coordinates, which moves together with the centre of mass of a rigid body, but does not rotate with it (keeps constant orientation with respect to any inertial frame).

Comment: @JakubSkórka Then edit your question above by adding this assumption. The way it is stated currently, your question doesn't reveal what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Linear and angular momentum conservation continues in non-inertial frames when fictitious forces are introduced.

For a non-rotating frame, applying a force $F = -ma$ where $a$ is the acceleration of the frame relative to an inertial is sufficient.

This force is applied to the center of mass of an object.  If you are analyzing the angular momentum about an axis that passes through the center of mass, then the fictitious force supplies no torque and can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The angular momentum (vector) of a moving rigid body can be decomposed into two parts. One is due to the motion of the center of mass, and the other from the rotation about the center of mass.

Start from a collection of particles, each with mass $m_i$, located at $\vec{r}_i$ and moving by $\vec{v}_i$ at each instant. Then define the angular momentum about the origin as $$ \vec{L}_0 = \sum_i \vec{r}_i \times m_i \vec{v}_i $$

Now if the particles move as a rigid body, the only allowed motion is that characterized by rectilinear motion. Without loss of generality, the motion is the translation of the center of mass $\vec{v}_{\rm com}$ and rotation about the center of mass $\vec{\omega}$, such that $$\vec{v}_i = \vec{v}_{\rm com} + \vec{\omega} \times (\vec{r}_i - \vec{r}_{\rm com})$$

Note that the definition of center of mass $\vec{r}_{\rm com} = \frac{ 1 }{m } \sum \limits_i m_i \vec{r}_i $, where $m = \sum \limits_i m_i$ is also expressed as

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  \sum_i m_i \vec{r}_i = m\, \vec{r}_{\rm com} \\
  \sum_i m_i \vec{v}_i = m\, \vec{v}_{\rm com}
\end{aligned}$$

Now we can expand the angular momentum expression

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  \vec{L}_0 & = \sum_i \vec{r}_i \times m_i \left( \vec{v}_{\rm com} + \vec{\omega} \times (\vec{r}_i - \vec{r}_{\rm com}) \right) \\
& =\left(\sum_{i}m_{i}\vec{r}_{i}\right)\times\vec{v}_{{\rm com}}+\sum_{i}m_{i}\vec{r}_{i}\times\left(\vec{\omega}\times\left(\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_{{\rm com}}\right)\right)\\
&=\vec{r}_{{\rm com}}\times m\vec{v}_{{\rm com}}-\vec{\omega}\times\sum_{i}\left(m_{i}\vec{r}_{i}\right)\times\vec{r}_{{\rm com}}-\sum_{i}m_{i}\left(\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_{{\rm com}}\right)\times\left(\vec{r}_{i}\times\vec{\omega}\right)\\
& =\vec{r}_{{\rm com}}\times m\vec{v}_{{\rm com}}-\sum_{i}m_{i}\vec{r}_{i}\times\left(\vec{r}_{i}\times\vec{\omega}\right)+\vec{r}_{{\rm com}}\times\left(\sum_{i}m_{i}\vec{r}_{i}\right)\times\vec{\omega}\\
& =\underbrace{\vec{r}_{{\rm com}}\times \vec{p}}_{\text{com movement}}+\underbrace{\sum_{i} m_{i}\vec{r}_{i}\times\left(\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}_{i} \right)}_{\text{rot. about com}}
\end{aligned} $$

where $\vec{p} = m\vec{v}_{{\rm com}} $ and the angular momentum about the center of mass is $$\vec{L}_{\rm com} = \sum_{i} m_{i}\vec{r}_{i}\times\left(\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}_{i} \right)$$ yielding the transformation law $$ \vec{L}_0 = \vec{L}_{\rm com} + \vec{r}_{\rm com} \times \vec{p}$$

In the absense of external torque, the angular momentum about the center of mass is conserved, since by definition

$$ \vec{\tau}_{\rm com} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \vec{L}_{\rm com} $$

which is proven by showing that

$$\vec{\tau}_{\rm com} = \sum_i \vec{r}_i \times \vec{F}_i = \sum_i \vec{r}_i \times  \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} (m_i \vec{v}_i) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \sum_{i} m_{i}\vec{r}_{i}\times\left(\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}_{i} \right)$$

So even if $\vec{L}_{\rm com}$ is conserved, the total angular momentum *not about the center of mass* $\vec{L}_0$ is not conserved if $\vec{v}_{\rm com} \neq 0$.